# Zooming in AS ScrollPane but I need to center on Mouse Location

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, zooming, mousewheel, scrollpane

I'm working in Flash ActionScript 3.  I have a stage with several options to click.  Clicking on each one opens a scroll pane (full screen 1920x1080) with an image (images vary in size, but all start at a height of 1080, and the width is usually 4000 or more.

I allow the user to scrollDrag to pan around and view the full image.  I have also added a zoom feature, where upon using the scroll wheel on the mouse, the image will zoom in and out a little.

What my problem is, I need to find a way to make it so that the zoom actually zooms in on the location where the mouse it when the wheel move is triggered.

I currently only let the zoom happen to a certain level (in and out).

I've tried several things involving content.x/y, content.width/height, horizontalScrollPosition and maxHorizontalScrollPosition, and I just can't seem to find the right formula to focus in on the right area.

I add the eventListener for the mouse wheel to my aSp2 Scrollpane, and here is the function it triggers:

```
function onMouseWheelEvent(MouseEvent):void{
    var mouseXPos = MouseEvent.stageX;
    var mouseYPos = MouseEvent.stageY;

    var imageWidth = aSp2.content.width;

    trace("ContentWidth = "+imageWidth+"\nmouse X = "+mouseXPos+"\nmouse Y = "+mouseYPos);









    if(MouseEvent.delta > 0){
        if(zoomCounter > 0){
            if(zoomCounter != 5){

            //var moveRight = aSp2.horizontalScrollPosition;
            //var moveDown = aSp2.verticalScrollPosition;


            //moveRight = moveRight + aSp2.content.width/2;
            //moveDown = moveDown + aSp2.content.height/2;

            //var centerX;
            //var centerY;


            //trace("MoveRight = "+moveRight+"\nMoveDown = "+moveDown);

            //trace("MaxWidthScroll = "+aSp2.maxHorizontalScrollPosition+"\nMaxHeightScroll = "+aSp2.maxVerticalScrollPosition);

            //trace("HScroll = "+aSp2.horizontalScrollPosition);
            //trace("Content X = "+aSp2.content.x);

            aSp2.content.scaleX += 1.1;
            aSp2.content.scaleY += 1.1;




            //aSp2.horizontalScrollPosition = aSp2.horizontalScrollPosition + aSp2.horizontalScrollPosition/2 ;
            //aSp2.verticalScrollPosition = aSp2.verticalScrollPosition + aSp2.verticalScrollPosition/2;

            aSp2.update();
            zoomCounter = zoomCounter - 1;
            }
        }
        if(zoomCounter == 5){
            aSp2.content.scaleX = 1;
            aSp2.content.scaleY = 1;

            aSp2.content.y = 0;


            aSp2.update();
            zoomCounter = 4;
        }

        trace("Zoom IN Count = "+zoomCounter);
    }else{
        if(zoomCounter == 4){
            scaleAmt = 1920/aSp2.content.width;

            aSp2.content.scaleX = scaleAmt;
            aSp2.content.scaleY = scaleAmt;

            aSp2.content.y = 520-(aSp2.content.height/2);


            aSp2.update();
            zoomCounter = 5;

        }
        if(zoomCounter < 4){

            aSp2.content.scaleX -= 1.1;
            aSp2.content.scaleY -= 1.1;
            aSp2.update();
            zoomCounter = zoomCounter + 1;
        }

        trace("Zoom OUT Count = "+zoomCounter);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word you are looking for is "Pivot" (in AS3 is called "registration point").

But here we have the fastest way to do it:
You should put your image inside a container Sprite

```
function reposition():void{
 var changex:Number=(container.x-zoomPt.x)/container.scaleX;
 var changey:Number=(container.y-zoomPt.y)/container.scaleX;
 container.x=zoomPt.x;
 container.y=zoomPt.y;
  for(var i:int=0;i<container.numChildren;i++){
      container.getChildAt(i).x+=changex;
      container.getChildAt(i).y+=changey;
   }
}
```

The complete guide is [here](http://as3adventure.blogspot.it/2010/10/zoom-to-point.html)